# Segue/ present controller from a ui table view controller not on story board to one on storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to segue to / present `SignInVC()` a table view controller that was made in storyboard, I currently start my app from `NewHomePageVC` which was made programatically / is not in storyboard , the current code below just takes me to a black screen (and it is no the case of `SignInVC` being just a black screen it has pictures, labels, text fields etc)  any idea's I would really appreciate it?

```
import UIKit

class NewHomePageVC: UITableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))    
    }

    func handleLogout() {  
        let loginController = SignInVC()
        present(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @JuicyFruit any ides on the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating an instance of `UIViewController`, not initiate it from `UIStoryboard`, easy way it to do this like:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) //"Main" - name of the storyboard
let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! SignInVC
self.present(loginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

where `loginVC` is an `ID` of `UIViewController`, which can be set in `Identity Inspector` of Storyboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JuicyFruit It worked, Amazing how you know these things